# How to search within a limited number of domains with Google?

Tags: google-search

Is there a feature in [Google Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Search) (advanced search, etc.) or in other Google products where you can limit your searches to only a specific set of sites?

I tried `searchterm site:xyz.com , abc.com`, but that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing

> searchterm site:abc.com OR
>   site:def.com

Real world example:

> Honda Civic site:edmunds.com OR
>   site:honda.com

Works.

Comment: Yes, it works...